# How to upgrade column hiding from react-table 6 to react-table 7

Tags: react-table, react-table-v7

Previous in react-table 6, one just added a `show: false` to the column spec to hide a column.

How can this be implemented in react-table 7?

Answer (score 1):

You can access `getToggleHiddenProps` property from the column.

According to the docs

[image]

You can check the demo:
https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-pasteur-dzk3k?file=/src/components/ColumnHiding.js

Also, if you want to hide some columns by default, add the accessors for the columns you want to hide and pass it as an array of strings to `initialState.hiddenColumns`

```
function Table({ columns, data }) {
   const {
      getTableProps,
      getTableBodyProps,
      headerGroups,
      rows,
      allColumns,
      getToggleHideAllColumnsProps,
      prepareRow
   } = useTable({
      initialState: {
         hiddenColumns: ["firstName"]
      },
      columns,
      data
   });
   // usual table markup from here on
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is more than one way to do this, but one way is to respond to the show property in from your column spec.

In your react-table 7 code that outputs the header:

eg.

```
headerGroup.headers.map(column => {
  return ( <TableCell> column.render('Header') </TableCell> )
})
```

add a filter:

eg.

```
headerGroup.headers..filter(column => column.show !== false).map(column => {
  return ( <TableCell> column.render('Header') </TableCell> )
})
```

And you your react-table 7 code that outputs your rows:

eg.

```
 {row.cells.map(cell =>
                        {
                            return (
                                <TableCell {...cell.getCellProps({ className: cell.column.className })}>
                                    {cell.render('Cell')}
                                </TableCell>
                            );
                        })}
```

add a filter:

eg.

```
 {row.cells.filter(cell => cell.column.show !== false).map(cell =>
                        {
                            return (
                                <TableCell {...cell.getCellProps({ className: cell.column.className })}>
                                    {cell.render('Cell')}
                                </TableCell>
                            );
                        })}
```